# Linking between buttons in Android via drag and drop?

Tags: android-studio, button, android-activity

Is Android Studio simple as Xcode and its storyboards?
So can I link between activities/views with drag an drop like in Xcode? Or is all linking to do with code?

Comment: Whats stopping you from installing it an trying it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities in Android work strictly through code. There is no easy linking like there is in Xcode. 
You would have found this if you actually Googled as good as you said ;)

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: THX ;-) - I thought so, because Ive found no context-menu or other stuff ;-) But maybe it become eeasier with Android-Studio in the future...